# Ngclass not updating the class in UI

Tags: angular

I am working on a chat application and am trying to show the online/offline status using `ngClass`. 
Here is my html code:

**html**

```
<i [ngClass]="{ 'fa': true,   'fa-circle': true, 'onlinestatus': true, 'online': isOnline == true, 'offline': isOnline == false}"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Now, I am using `websockets` for real time chat and whenever a new-message comes, I want to change the status to `online`, so I set `isOnline` to true.

Here is my `component.ts` code

**component.ts**

```
isOnline = false;
ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.on("new-message", (data) => {
        this.isOnLine = true;
        this.messages.push(data.message);

    });
}
```

The `socket` works perfectly and new messages are shown. On debugging, even the `isOnline` is being set to `true`. But in the UI, I still see the gray color for `offline` class. On inspect in developer tools, I still see the `offline` class attached to `i` element.

Comment: You're doing `isOnLine = true`, but the `ngClass` is checking for `isOnline`

Comment: ah, sorry for this silly mistake. Strange, my `code editor` didn't throw up an error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use `[class.fa]="condition"` or `[class]="{rules}"`